# Android custom color picker: Draw triangle with gradient

Tags: android, gradient, color-picker

I'm new to Android developpment and want to create my own colorpicker. Therefore i want to create a triangle with the colors red, green, blue in the corners and the other colors as a gradient in between.

I did not find any way in Androi to create such a gradient with 3 origin points and therefore I wanted to ask you guys, what's the best way to go about this problem :)

(I'd rather not just use an image because the brightness with a gradient i could ajust the brightness of the triangle, also the solution should be as clean and performant as possible)

Thanks for your help! Cheers

Comment: i would start with `android.graphics.ComposeShader` and play with different `PorterDuff.Mode`s

Answer (score 1):

You can create xml file like this in drawable folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt"
    android:height="100dp"
    android:width="120dp"
    android:viewportHeight="100"
    android:viewportWidth="100">
        <path android:pathData="m 50,0 l 50,100 -100,0 z" >
            <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
                <gradient
                    android:endX="0"
                    android:endY="100">
                        <item android:color="#F20600" android:offset="0.1111111" />
                        <item android:color="#FF7600" android:offset="0.22222222" />
                        <item android:color="#FFD500" android:offset="0.3333333" />
                        <item android:color="#8CFE00" android:offset="0.44444444" />
                        <item android:color="#00E86C" android:offset="0.5555555" />
                        <item android:color="#00E86C" android:offset="0.6666666" />
                        <item android:color="#00CCFF" android:offset="0.77777777" />
                        <item android:color="#013CE0" android:offset="0.8888888" />
                        <item android:color="#013CE0" android:offset="0.9999999" />
                </gradient>
            </aapt:attr>
        </path>
</vector>
```

You can use your desired colors :)

Then set ImageView src:

```
 <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/triangle"
        android:src="@drawable/triangle"
        />
```

The result:

[image]